# awk add a value to field

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm looking for an idea about how to add a value to a field my file looks like this:

```
line(001)=YR200PR1030,YR230PR1580,YR340PR2016,
          YR450PR2450,
          PRF3500,
line(002)=YR200PR452,YR230PR740,YR340PR1500,
          YR450PR2120,
          PRF2800,
```

and i want to add a value of 32 to each value between YR and PR , so ex:
 `YR200PR1030` --> `YR232PR1030`

any idea? thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If what you need is to increment the numerical value found between every occurrence of `YR` and `PR`, you could try:

```
$ perl -pe 's/YR(\d+)PR/sprintf("YR%sPR",$1 + 32)/eg' file
line(001)=YR232PR1030,YR262PR1580,YR372PR2016,
          YR482PR2450,
          PRF3500,
line(002)=YR232PR452,YR262PR740,YR372PR1500,
          YR482PR2120,
          PRF2800,
```

Or, to edit the file in place:

```
perl -i -pe 's/YR(\d+)PR/sprintf("YR%sPR",$1 + 32)/eg' file
```

The `-pe` means "**p**rint every line after applying the script given by -e". The script itself is just a substitution operator (`s/old/new/`) with the `/g` flag for "global" (match every occurrence on the line) and the `/e` which allows us to execute code in the right hand side of the operator. Finally, the regex will match one or more digits (`\d+`) between a `YR` and a `PR`, capturing the digits as `$1`, and then the replacement will print `YR`, the number captured plus 32 and `PR`.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/YR[0-9]+PR/) ) {
        printf "%s%d", substr($0,1,RSTART+1), substr($0,RSTART+2)+32
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-2)
    }
    print
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
line(001)=YR232PR1030,YR262PR1580,YR372PR2016,
          YR482PR2450,
          PRF3500,
line(002)=YR232PR452,YR262PR740,YR372PR1500,
          YR482PR2120,
          PRF2800,
```

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
for ((j=1;j<=2;j++)); do awk -v j="$j" -F "," 'NR==j && ORS=","{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /^YR[0-9]*PR[0-9]*/){print substr($i,1,2)substr($i,3,3)+32substr($i,6)}else {print $i}}}' p.txt; echo -e "\n"; done
```

output

```
YR232PR1030,YR262PR1580,YR372PR2016,YR482PR2450,

YR232PR452,YR262PR740,YR372PR1500,YR482PR2120,PRF2800,
```